# How to wrap words or words sequences which have not been already wrapped?

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word, text-analysis

I'm trying to wrap words and words sequence from a given list with preg_replace. It almost works, but there are some use cases it doesn't and I can't figure it how.

For instance I do this:

```
    // sort by descending length
    usort($this->_keywords, function($a,$b){return(strlen($a)<strlen($b));});

    // wrapper is -%string%-
    foreach ($this->_keywords as $keyword) {
        $value = preg_replace('/((?!-)' . $keyword . '(?!-))/i', str_replace('%string%', '\1', $this->_wrapper), $value);
    }
```

From this keyword list:

- lorem
- ipsum
- sit amet
- null
- sed
- sed enim

I'd like to result in:

> **-Lorem-**  **-ipsum-** dolor **-sit amet-**,
>   consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
>   rhoncus venenatis orci sed porta. Sed
>   non dolor eros. Suspendisse a massa
>   **-sit amet-** nulla egestas facilisis. Cras
>   fringilla, leo ac ullamcorper semper,
>   urna eros pretium lectus, nec rhoncus
>   ligula risus eu velit. Nulla eu
>   dapibus magna. Sed vehicula tristique
>   lacinia. Maecenas tincidunt metus at
>   urna consequat nec congue libero
>   iaculis. Nulla facilisi. Phasellus **-sed-**
>   sem ut risus mattis accumsan eu **-sed
>   enim-**. Pellentesque habitant morbi
>   tristique senectus et netus et
>   malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
>   Suspendisse id est velit, eu cursus
>   quam. Vivamus lacinia euismod pretium.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the specific problem you are having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved my problems by using the `\b` metacharacters which correspond to a word boundary.

```
public function filter($value)
{
    usort($this->_keywords, function($a,$b){return(strlen($a)<strlen($b));});

    foreach ($this->_keywords as $keyword) {
        $value = preg_replace(
            '/((?<!-)('.$keyword.'\b)(?!\-))/i',
            str_replace('%string%', '\2', $this->_wrapper) . '\3',
            $value
        );
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is to use `preg_replace_callback()`, and match words that already has been wrapped, and each keyword. When the match is a word that has been wrapped, just return it unmodified. No need for problematic look-arounds.

```
function compare_length($a, $b) {
    return strlen($a) < strlen($b);
}

function build_regex($keywords) {
    usort($keywords, 'compare_length');
    $pieces []= '/(?<wrapped>-[\w\s]*-)|(?<keyword>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($pieces); $i++) {
        if ($i > 0) $pieces []= '|';
        $pieces []= preg_quote($keywords[$i], '/');
    }
    $pieces []= ')/';
    return implode("", $pieces);
}

function wrap_callback($match) {
    if (!empty($match['wrapped'])) {
        return $match['wrapped'];
    }
    return "-{$match['wrapped']}-";
}

function wrap($text, $keywords) {
    $regex = build_regex($keywords);
    return preg_replace_callback($regex, 'wrap_callback');
}
```